# PHP/MYSQL - multi tables in one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 6 tables to display in one query. I'm trying three tables first but there's an error, and I don't know why. I want to show all fields, but I tried the first item code if going to work. Unfortunately, there's a bug.

The error is **`Warning: mysqli::query() [mysqli.query]: (21000/1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row in C:\wamp\www\DASMA\stockcard.php on line 541`**

I want to display all the data in my all table whether one of it don't have data yet. Just without using SQL join.

```
   |allinvty3|(masterfile)
      ----------------
      |in_code       |
      |ecr_desc      |
      |pric_cash  
      |qty           |
      |ite_desc      |
      ---------------


 |(barcode, soldout_dm , dm_stock_transfer, adjustment etc. 
    -all have same fieldname)|
              ----------------
              |itemcode      |
              |qty           |
              |date  
              |qty           |
              |status        |
              ---------------
<?php
$sql = "
    SELECT  (
    SELECT itemcode as bcode
    FROM   barcode 
    ) ,
    ( 
    SELECT itemcode as bsold
    FROM   soldout_dm 
    ) ,
    (
    SELECT itemcode as  bstock
    FROM   dm_stock_transfer
    ) 
    ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question with dummy data and table structure. This seems to be related with `JOIN`

Comment: Your sub query return multiple row because you didn't add where condition. You should make sure that each sub query return maximum 1 result. You can share your tables and expected result.

Comment: also add column in main SELECT `SELECT bcode,bsold,bstock  
    (
      SELECT itemcode as bcode
      FROM barcode 
    ),
    ( 
      SELECT itemcode as bsold
      FROM soldout_dm 
    ) ,
    (
      SELECT itemcode as  bstock
      FROM dm_stock_transfer
    ) FROM TABLE` something like

Comment: i have tried everything but still there's an error. thanks for the effort guys.

Comment: Try this: `$sql = " SELECT barcode.itemcode as bcode, soldout_dm.itemcode as bsold, dm_stock_transfer.itemcode as bstock FROM barcode, soldout_dm, dm_stock_transfer ";`   @codeSeven

Comment: what is the relation between the tables? is there any link between the fields?

Comment: all tables have itemcode fieldname so that's why sir

Comment: Do they all have the same number of columns and respective columns have the same name? If so, check UNION. Otherwise, you will need to give more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

$sql = 'select b.itemcode as bcode, s.itemcode as bsold, d.itemcode as bstock from barcode as b, soldout_dm as s, dm_stock_transfer as d';

$result = $con->query($sql);

?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 4456448) (tried to allocate 3932144 bytes)

Comment: You may change the php.ini to increase the max memory size that can allocate, or limit the rows that query return.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="select t1.column, t2.column,t3.column,t4.column,t5.column,t6.column from t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6 ";
```

this type of query will help you to get data from all six tables .

Comment: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 12320768) (tried to allocate 11796464 bytes) , i already edit memory limit in my php.ini

Comment: this is not memory error . this is another error . that can sometimes occur when mistake is in loop or code .